# how to modify array that each item is array in php (clarify in description)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i had a array to each its item was object , i've converted that array with following code :

```
json_decode(json_encode($array), true)
```

that the result of code was a array like this  :

```
[
  '1'=>[
   'slug'=>'a'
   'title'=>'foo' 
  ],
  '2'=>[
   'slug'=>'b'
   'title'=>'bar' 
  ],
  '3'=>[
   'slug'=>'c'
   'title'=>'foo' 
  ],
]
```

now i want to covert this array to somethings like this

```
 [
   'a'=>'foom',
   'b'=>'bar',
   'c'=>'foo',
 ]
```

how can i do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use foreach and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array-combine)

```
foreach ($your_array as $key => $value) {
  // get all the keys in $slug array
  $slug[] = $value['slug'];
  // get all the values in $title array
  $title[] = $value['title'];
}
// finally combine and get your required array
$required_array = array_combine($slug, $title);
```

I think it can also be acheived with -

```
$requiredArray = array_combine(
   array_column($your_array, 'slug'), 
   array_column($your_array, 'title')
);
```

Comment: thnks @jitendrapurohit the second way work like a charm , the first way is currect too and i've test it before but there are alot of item in the array so it seems a little cheap .

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the initial array and create the new one like this:

```
$array = [
  '1'=>[
   'slug'=>'a'
   'title'=>'foo' 
  ],
  '2'=>[
   'slug'=>'b'
   'title'=>'bar' 
  ],
  '3'=>[
   'slug'=>'c'
   'title'=>'foo' 
  ],
];

$result = [];
foreach($array as $elem){
   $index = $elem["slug"];
   $value= $elem["title"];
   $result[$index] = $value; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $elem){
    $result[$elem["slug"]] = $elem["title"]; 
}
```